# Null character in input file

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are migrating informatica from windows to Unix as a result when I was running workflow in windows which consists of 10 sessions, getting succeeded.

But same workflow (code) has been migrated to unix Environment. However workflow getting failed due to NULL character in input file.

EX:

> FR_3085: 513th character is a null character, which is not allowed in a text input file

Don't know where went wrong, as other 9 sessions(out of 10) getting succeeded.

Comment: At least let me know the approach to overcome this NULL character in inputfile

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 2 approaches in this case :

1. Replace the null character in the file using SED or any other Linux commad/method before workflow run.
2. User given custom properties at your session/workflow.

https://kb.informatica.com/solution/6/Pages/20698.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Thank you...Ankur for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you are on RHL  sometimes the conversion from Window to Shell script will bring Unicode characters.

Try running `dos2unix filename.txt` command and then convert the file format to Unix. After doing this run the workflow.

Also you can check whether the file has Unicode or not by running `cat -v filename.txt`

Comment: Thnk you..Aswin for your response